# Did the recent Safari 5.1 upgrade break my Vienna display styles?

Tags: safari, software-update, css

I recently installed the latest round of system updates to my Snow-Leopard MacBook Pro (10.6.8), and my Vienna reader is afflicted with ugly.  Example:

[image: Ugly!]

And also

[image: Ugly still!]

For reference, these are FeedLight and Bohemian Broadsheet styles.

None of the styles (all 15 installed defaults) allow changing from anything but this default HTML-from-1996 styles.  It used to use CSS, I think, to format the feeds.  Anyone else having issues like this?  Is there a simple fix?  I've obviously tried restarting the apps, both Safari and Vienna, and nothing seems to make any difference.  I'm sure it's possible some /Library file is responsible, but I don't know which one or how to determine which one.  Anyone?

Comment: As far as I know Safari 5.1 now uses Webkit2, which is built from the ground up. Perhaps this change is causing the problem. Just throwing this out there.
Hope you find a solution to your problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer:  Yes.

Due to complications with Sparkle updates, according to this [thread](http://forums.cocoaforge.com/viewtopic.php?f=18&t=23380), the 'check for updates' process did not find the latest version.  Webkit2 has some additional security considerations, apparently.  Upgrading to 2.5.1.2502 is the solution.